# MySQL Procedure IN variable don't work properly

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm learning Functions, Procedures and Triggers and I wanted to do a easy procedure that count the rows in a table from parameters.

```
create procedure countRows(IN v varchar(30))
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM v;
```

Can someone tell me why if I do:

```
call countRows('sometable'); 
call countRows(sometable); //I tried both
```

It just don't work

Sorry for that newbie question.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? How is it failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need dynamic sql.

**Solution for returning count of any table passed as a parameter to sp**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `countRows`(IN v varchar(30))
    BEGIN
    SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  ",V);
     PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
     EXECUTE stmt3;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
   END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Execution

```
call countRows('sometable');
```

**Update: Solution for returning "Table x contain n row(s)" for a table passed as a parameter to sp**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `countRowsEx`(IN v VARCHAR(30))
    BEGIN
    -- SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  ",V);
    SET @t1 =CONCAT('SET @totalRows=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  ',v, ' );');
     PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
     EXECUTE stmt3;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
     SELECT CONCAT( 'Table ', v, ' contains ', @totalRows, ' row', IF(@totalRows>1, 's',''));
   END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Execution**

```
call countRowsEx('sometable');
```

Comment: You should probably add the delimiter `delimiter // create procedure .....end;// delimiter ;` however +1 for the only correct answer so far.

Comment: Excuse me Anir, what If I want to return the value like: The table X contains X rows. It took a long time trying but I still can't get that working.

Comment: @Edw4rd, I haved added solution to your requirement "The table X contains N rows", please check updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use information_schema for this.

for example to find rows count for table with name stored in variable v use this:

```
select table_rows from information_schema.tables where table_name = v;
```

Comment: You answer with dynamic sql is better.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
call countRows('v');
```